# bootstrap border-bottom links only text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this menu :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MyWeb</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Features">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Download">Downloads</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I try to make a custom underline of 4 pixels but only for the text.

I tried this :

```
navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
     border-bottom : 4px solid black ;
}
```

but then the border-bottom takes the whole space

How can I make it work so only the text is underlined not the whole li ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**CSS:**

```
<style>
        navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 100px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        span {
            border-bottom: 4px solid;
        }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

see here 
**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23488/)**

well with bootstrap `a` has the `padding` so if you want to add the border to `a` and the `a` not to be as wide as the `li` , remove `padding` from `a` and add `padding` to `li`

CSS

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
   border-bottom : 4px solid black ;
   padding:0;
 } 
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li {
  padding:15px;
}
```